# Hide first item and show first hidden item with loop

Tags: jquery, loops, html-lists, show-hide

How to loop through ul li list with jquery. Hide **first item** and show **first hidden item**.

I didn't find anything similiar, so I want to post my script here.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<ul id="neue_bst">
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">1) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">2) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">3) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">4) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">5) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">6) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">7) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">8) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">9) Baustelle</div></li>
  <li><div class="fa fa-grip-lines"></div><div class="text_bst">10) Baustelle</div></li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
var list = $('#neue_bst li:gt(8)');
list.hide();
    
setInterval(function() {
    
   var me = $('#neue_bst li').first();
   $('#neue_bst li').eq(1).hide();
    
   $('#neue_bst li').parent().append(me);
   $('li:last').hide();
    
   $('#neue_bst li').eq(8).fadeIn(500);
    
 }, 2000);
```